# Github - Upload folder

Tags: git, github, directory

I want to upload a folder which contains files to a github using git bash so that my github displays a folder and when I click on it files are displayed. I want to know the steps since I'm a beginner with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+for+beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new GitHub Repository and follow the steps shown(I will write it down here, too)

- Open the folder in git bash
- create a local repository by executing `git init`
- add the content of the directory: `git add .`
- commit that to the local repository: `git commit -m "your yommit message"`
- add the GitHub repository as a remote: `git remote add origin <link to the repository>`
- Push(upload) your local changes to GitHub: `git push -u origin master`

Comment: so i need to open my folder, which will then show me files and then open git bash for 1st step?

Comment: like my folder xyz. inside xyz are files so i need to open git bash inside xyz or outside xyz?

Comment: Right click and `Open with Git Bash` (if it is enabled) or open git bash and run `cd <path to your folder>`

Comment: Open it inside - the folder you open will be uploaded to github.

Comment: If the path of the folder is `xyz`: yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203487/discussion-between-fatimah-ali-and-dan1st).

Comment: If it is `/home/<username>/xyz` or `C:\Users\<username>\xyz`, it will be that. Depends where the folder is located.